# Trying to fix possible SQL injection in the update method. Line 286

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have a project that uses Oracle Db. after running vulnerability scan using Veracode scan, it shows that there is a possible SQL injection vulnerability specifically on line 286 on the above image.

To fix it, I have updated all the queries to used prepared statement, AddParm() and added validation but this warning is still coming up. I notice when I comment out that particular line the warning no longer comes up after running the scan again.

```
    public int Update()
    {
        try
        {
            int num = 0;
            using (conn)
            {
                this.cmd.CommandTimeout = 180;
    
                num = this.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // scan is flagging this line
            }
            this.Close();
            return num;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.PaintError(ex);
    
            this.Close();
    
            return -1;
        }
    
    }
```

// below is an example of where the update method is being referenced.

```
public dynamic UpdateRMethod(RMthodRequest request)
 {
     
         string sql = $@"UPDATE XYZ SET CREDITXYZ = :xyz WHERE NO_Prop = :xyz_info";

         Connect cn = new Connect("constring");
         cn.SetSQL(sql);
         cn.AddParam(":xyz", request.xProp);
         cn.AddParam(":xyz_info", request.cProp);
         var ds = cn.Update();
 }
```

Please is there an alternative or a way around this. "num = this.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();"

To resolve this issue, I validated the inputs and also ensured that the inputs are not being passed directly into the queries.

Comment: Welcome to the SO. Please read [ask] and provide a [mre]. Possibly this question would be better addressed to the `Veracode` tech support.

Comment: That warning won't go away until you remove that way of executing SQL and use parameterised SQL statements and stored procedures instead.

Comment: to elaborate Dijkgraaf, you should check out [owasp's explanation on sql injection and why its dangerous](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection). its kinda hard to tell what `cmd` do but as long as it involve any string manipulation most scanner consider it vulnerable.

Comment: `num = this.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` just *executes* **vulnerable** query. Please, provide code where you *create* the sql.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with a complete example of the code that includes where you **SET** the value of `this.cmd` and an example of the SQL that you are trying to execute. We cannot debug code that we cannot see.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the response. @Dijkgraaf I am currently using parameterized SQL statements. What would be an alternative to using the update method as implemented in my code. I have updated my question to include a snippet of where the update method is being called.